# Custom 3D Views for Android

Tags: android, view, gallery, custom-view

I am about to start working on a new android app . The app is concerned with showing Images at most of the instances . I want to know if there are any cool custom views available for Presenting images more beautifully . The GridView and the Gallery views are too simple . Some 3D view will be great . Actually i am inspired form the Gallery3D app . . are there any free libraries available for this . Thank You

Comment: Take a look at [android opengl](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) and the sample apps come with it. If my memory serves there's an example does exactly what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the ios cover flow? There is an Android Project, that implements the same. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/HelgePlaschke/Android-Cover-Flow-Widget).

Comment: Thanks a lot Ahmad !!! This is exactly what i was looking for . And sorry i cannot vote up ! I do not have enough reputation . I hope my comment will make others vote up your answer . Anyways thanks a Lot :)